# PHP program to accept user input and terminate when entered zero

Tags: php, command-line

I came across this program on http://www.programmr.com .  And the question is 
**Complete the program to print the sum of negative numbers, positive even numbers, positive odd numbers from a list of numbers entered by the user. The list terminates when the number entered is zero** . And my code is,

```
$nums = array();

while(trim(fgets(STDIN)) != 0){
    array_push($nums,trim(fgets(STDIN)));
}
```

I know the code is incomplete but what im trying to do is to push the inputs to the array and then calculate the sum. When I `print_r($nums)` the array it gives me this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 34
    [1] => 32
    [2] => 45
    [3] => 0
)
```

And my input is,

```
 12
 34
 12
 32
 12
 45
 12
 0
 0
```

It pushes the alternative elements i dont know whats happening with this. Please help me , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling fgets(STDIN) twice in your code, i have adjusted it a bit so the array part is working. The rest of the assignment i let you figure that part out ;) Hint: Use modulus operator.

```
$nums = array();

do {
    $number = (int) trim(fgets(STDIN));
    array_push($nums,$number);
} while ($number !== 0);

print_r($nums);
```

Also if you are using PHP5.6 or higher you can use short array syntax like so:

```
$nums = [];
```

And

```
$nums[] = $number;
```